# detecting indexPath row and pushing a new view controller to a split view controller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller that has a table on the left hand side, and a empty detail view controller on the right had side. For iphone, I know its possible to push a view controller and a nib in a navigational stack. I want to know if its possible to push a view controller + nib on the detail view, after a user taps the table cell.
I tried simply pushing the view i have after a user taps to the detail view, however nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need to make sure you have a UINavigationController on the detail side of your split view controller.  You can set a navigation controller as the detail item within the nib that contains the split view.  You can set the navigation controller as the split view delegate and use the delegate property to push views onto the stack in response to events happening on the root view side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just going to the developer.apple.com and use the standard example from Apple, which does exactly what ur saying?

Cell 1 = loads Xib1

Cell 2 = loads Xib2.

Maybe give that a go..

Answer (score 0):

ya u can do that check out this example here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

and to make navigation controller in detailview of split view check example here

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/

i think it will help you